# Make alignments with different views so that they are center aligned with each other

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

```
Android Studio 3.5.3
```

I have the following xml and using constraintLayout to align a 2 views and TextView with each other. However, The views need to be fixed at a MarginTop of 45dp. I need to adjust the MarginTop of the textview to get them to look like they are horizontally aligned. I think there must be a better way. So basically, the Views need to be MarginTop of 45dp and the TextView should look like its aligned horizontally without having to adjust the MarginTop to try and compensate.

```
     <View
        android:id="@+id/lineRight"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tvOr"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/bt_login"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvOr"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_regular"
        android:text="OR"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/bt_login" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/lineLeft"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tvOr"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/bt_login"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
```

And this is an image of what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can vertically constrain the `tvOr` to one of the views, let's say the left one, and remove the marginTop like this:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvOr"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_regular"
        android:text="OR"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/lineLeft"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/lineLeft"/>
```

This way the TextView will be centered vertically with the left line.

Comment: Thanks, seems like `app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/lineLeft"` did the trick